# Extending $Z_p$ to $Z_p[\alpha]$ and Showing $|Z_p[\alpha]| = p^2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $i(x) = x^2 - [b]$ be an irreducible 2nd degree polynomial in $Z_p[x]$ for $p$ a prime integer and $[b] \in Z_p$. (The fact that $i(x)$ exists has been shown elsewhere).  Then $i(x)$ doesn't have any roots in $Z_p$.  So let us extend $Z_p$ to $Z_p[\alpha]$ s.t. $\alpha$ *is* a root of $i(x)$.

**Goal:** Show that $|Z_p[\alpha]| = p^2$.

**Attempt:** Below I show that there are at least $p$ new elements in $Z_p[\alpha]$.

1. Let $[k],[j] \in Z_p$ then we have that $[k] + \alpha = [j] + \alpha$ implies that $[k] = [j]$. Furthermore, we have that each $[k] + \alpha$ is not in $Z_p$, for otherwise $([k] + \alpha) - [k] = \alpha$ would imply that $\alpha \in Z_p$, a contradiction.
2. So there are at least $p$ new elements in $Z_p[\alpha]$.  Namely, $\alpha, [1] + \alpha, [2] + \alpha, \ldots , [p-1] + \alpha$.  Call these $p$ new elements $a_1, \ldots , a_p$.

Now I could continue to multiply and add $Z_p \cup \{a_i\}$ to try to generate the rest of the $p^2 - 2p$ elements, but I'm not sure this is the right approach.  How do I show that $|Z_p[\alpha]| = p^2$?

Comment: How exactly are you constructing $\mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$? This sort of thing really depends on your definitions. If you are constructing it as a quotient of a polynomial ring, then its cardinality essentially follows from the division algorithm (for polynomials). If you are constructing it by ad-hoc tacking a new symbol $\alpha$ onto $\mathbb{Z}_p$, it's almost "by definition".

Comment: What do you mean in the latter case?

Comment: Hopefully someone else can jump in...I have to run to class. If no ones answers, I'll try to do so later today.

Comment: Is $\;Z_p=\Bbb Z_p:=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ or the $\;p-$adic integers?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p := \mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear (to me, at least) how you construct the extension $\;\Bbb Z_p[\alpha]\;$ but it seems to be you use the quotient ring

$$\Bbb Z_p[\alpha]\cong\Bbb Z_p[x]/\langle x^2-b\rangle$$

Now, show that every element in the extension can be represented as $\;cx+d+\langle b\rangle\;$ in the quotient, and that two different elements like this one are different in the quotient, which already gives you $\;p\cdot p=p^2\;$ elements.

Another approach: we know every field is a linear space over *any* subfield, and since the quotient above is a field (why?), it is a linear space over $\;\Bbb Z_p\;$ . Now show that $\;\left\{1+\langle b\rangle\;,\;x+\langle b\rangle\right\}\;$ is a basis for our space and, again but this time by basic combinatorics, we get $\;p^2\;$ elements .

Note that in fact we can put $\;\alpha=x+\langle b\rangle\;$ ...